# Generating first names based on race/ethnicity

Tags: names

I want to generate some fake people for a piece of software I'm writing. These people also have ethnicities, and I'd prefer not to have names that don't look totally out of place when compared to those ethnicities.

My first idea was to base it on data. There is [a table of first and last names from the 1990 US census](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/data/1990surnames/names_files.html) with attached frequencies, but that says nothing about ethnicity. There is also [a table of last names from the 2000 US census which is broken down by ethnicity](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/data/2000surnames/), but it says nothing about first names.

So I need some way of generating first names based on ethnicity. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you are writing the next XCOM game :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [behindthename.com](http://www.behindthename.com/usage.php). They have very extensive lists of names by usage, including lists of popular names.

Comment: Thank you. That helps for some ethnicities, but (unless I'm missing something) it doesn't help with ethnicities that can't be defined by a country, like the African American population in the US.

Comment: You can look at [english names](http://www.behindthename.com/nmc/eng.php) and you'll notice that the african american ones are marked as such (for example "ANTWAN   m   English (African American)").

Comment: Ah, I see. Not as comprehensive as census data and no frequency information besides rare or not rare, but it's a start. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy, well, it depends on what you're looking for. If you want african american names, you could consult other sources, such as http://babynamesworld.parentsconnect.com/category-african-american-names.html. You likely won't find everything in one place.

Comment: Ideally I'd like something similar to the census data on last names by ethnicity, but for first names. A database of first names sorted by frequency and ethnicity, just like the database of last names. I'm realizing that probably no such perfect data source exists, and what you link to is probably the best I'll find. I sent an email to the census people too, as undoubtedly someone there does have this data even if they haven't put it online.

Answer (score 3):

The site http://www.babynamefacts.com/ contains lists of most popular baby names per country.  This may be a good starting point.  For example, this page shows the most popular baby names for Serbia in 2009: http://www.babynamefacts.com/popularnames/countries.php?country=SRB .

Comment: Thank you. That helps for some ethnicities, but it doesn't help with ethnicities that can't be defined by a country, like the African American population in the US.